# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I opened a trial account on Google Cloud and I'm having difficulties connection to Cloud SQL.

I made the basic setup, authorizing my IP/32 && adding a new User (appUser).

But I can't open a remote connection to the instance.

```
mysql -v --host=<ip> --user=appUser --password
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ip>' (60)
```

I'm at work and obviously behind a ton of firewalls and whatnot. Could this be the cause of my problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good change that it is a firewall problem. Error 2003 (from [MySQL client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-client.html) manual) means that it can't connect to the server.

Can you try to connect through a computer outside the firewall?